How to mock a top-level extension class function in Kotlin?
I've got some Kotlin code that defines an extension function (anExtensionMethod) on a 3P-provided class (RdsClient):
// MyLib.kt

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.rds.RdsClient
public fun RdsClient.anExtensionMethod(): String {
  return "hi"
}

In the unit test, I want to mock anExtensionMethod, like so:
// MyLibTest.kt
import com.tecton.orchestrator.monitoring.anExtensionMethod
  @Test
  fun testIt() {
    var mockRdsClient_: RdsClient = mock { on { anExtensionMethod() } doReturn "bob" }
    ...

At runtime, I get a org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException failure:
1) testAllMetricsAreCollected(...)
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

        at com.tecton.orchestrator.monitoring.RDSMetricsCollectorModuleTest.testIt(MyTest.kt:..)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1

I've found lots of suggestions to use mockkStatic, but thus far none of the permutations of that function have solved the issue. I suspect there is some nuance to this particular situation: the class-to-be-mocked is from a 3P library; the extension method is defined via top-level function. Any pointers on resolving this mock error are appreciated!

I may have made some progress with          mockkStatic("com.tecton.orchestrator.monitoring.RDSMetricsCollectorModuleKt"); I'll update this thread if/when I get a passing version.

Confirmed: I had gotten the mockkStatic invocation a bit mucked up. It turns out that mockkStatic("com.tecton.orchestrator.lib.rds.RdsHelperKt") works (that's the package path to the file-in-which-I-defined-the-extension-functions, plus the Kt suffix).
